# link to local server files in a DT in RMarkdown

Tags: r, data.table, r-markdown

Trying to link to local server files inside a DataTable View.

Files are located on my server home folder, so links are actually linking to a local folder from Rmarkdown but remote folder from the user's browser.

Desired result is user opening Rmarkdown in a browser with datatable view and clicking a link then file is opened or downloaded.

```
   # df is a dataframe of filenames

    location <- "/home/user/files/"

    dt$link<- paste0("[",dt$Filename,"](", location,df$Filename ")")

    require(DT)

    datatable(df, rownames = F, filter = "top")
```

Filename column is rendered as simple text, no blue color, no hover , no link to file...

Regards

Comment: `require(datatable)` -- do you mean `require(DT)`?

Comment: You're right nrussell

Comment: Not duplicated as the other is for Shiny. Mine is for Rmarkdown

Comment: `datatable` renders HTML AFAIK; did you try making a proper HTML link (i.e. with an anchor element) and prefixing the file path with `file:///`?

Comment: so, code will be?:  paste0("<a href=file:///", location,dt$Filename , ">", dt$Filename , "</a>")

Comment: `sprintf('<a href="file:///%s">%s</a>', dt$Filename, dt$Filename)` should work (note that the link given to `href` needs to be surrounded by quotes *in* the HTML code). Also, you need to specify `escape = FALSE` in the `datatable` expression.

Comment: Did'nt know that "pythonesque" trick. Worked rendering a proper link (even the document is not downloaded or opened, I imagine permission issues)! Thanks nrussell